# Content Statistics: Total View not showing up in Services

Tags: services

I'm pretty sure this worked the other day, but today I checked and it didn't appear in my `Services`

If I add a new field such as `body`, it appears in my `json` file.. When I add `Content Statistics: Total Views` it won't add it.

I tried doing it a dirty way by adding a `Global Text` and use a replacement pattern, but then it outputs it like: `[totalcount]`

Also worth noting I can see it in the preview.

Comment: it sounds to me as a permission problem. are you seeing this as admin or opening it in another browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, this is a permission problem and it is possible that only admin is allowed to see that view.

You can set the permissions in the view itself so that it is available to all users otherwise just log-in as Admin to see the 'view'.